# What is this code segment telling me?

Tags: c, linux, process

```
pid_t pid; int status;
   if ((pid = wait(&status)) > 0) {
      printf("4");
   }
```

I know that wait() forces a parent process to wait for a child process to stop or
terminate. wait() return the pid of the child or -1 for an error

I dont understand what this statement is doing.

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function wait() returns the ID of the completed process for the non-error case.  The process ID is a positive integer.

```
if ((pid = wait(&status)) > 0) {
```

simply checks whether a process ID was returned (as opposed to an error code), and for whatever reason then outputs `4`.